# Creating a linked server for connecting to excel file

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel-2010

I want to create a linked server for connecting to excel file and i have used below address for doing that:
https://www.sqlshack.com/query-excel-data-using-sql-server-linked-servers/

After installing (accessdatabaseengine.exe) the provider has not been added to my provider in sql server.

When i wanted to install accessdatabaseengine_x64.exe i got error because office is 32 bit.

My office is 32 bit version and my sql server is 64 bit version. I do not have permit to re-install of my office and my sql server.

Please help how i can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Masoud,

Architecture versions have to match unfortunately so you would need to install 64-bit office to make that adaptor to work.

You could possibly use SSIS to a raw table and process that way but this depends on your workload and frequency of updates required.